# Yum user temp files (/var/tmp/yum*) fills up with repo data

Tags: rhel, yum, rpm, tmp

On my rhel6 system, non-sudo users can do yum check-update. Files are then placed in `/var/tmp/yum[user]*/` . The repodata there gets quite large. Can I:

1. Configure the location?
2. Configure yum so it removes old files?

My /var/tmp/yum-nrpe*/x86_64/6Server looks contains the following:

> ```
> 28M     el-6-epel/5f32b55aa431745fe8b48deb2e0083a6507d19abbc29562a2e2b01b70ef93ada-primary.sqlite
> 29M     el-6-epel/89f1177c1b9f003409e2f5a91f7f3074a4b8e162376ffab286a35b8221e0a308-primary.sqlite
> 29M     el-6-epel/b98f6809469e5de3a13a5b251c5d35c622baecb9f3c593804245c443ace9a224-primary.sqlite
> 29M     el-6-epel/c79dd64a4e4aa8fb160353e9cd9d8e10120f5402a18aca730ae860d07f52bda3-primary.sqlite
> 29M     el-6-epel/e4b306d444fcfb361f7f2aace64a3ef67c8bd7fd1cbd251e64f150096f2f1ba9-primary.sqlite
> 1.2M    el-6-comp-extra/6c04e2f2f68bc085d529d857dd6c0539ff23d5139d2be21565dac3d8e586bae0-primary.sqlite
> 15M     rhel-6-server-optional-rpms/2469dd815fb83f3667f043cf3098a487a13ac6955ea36b2349bdc3a2ee1e20d2-primary.sqlite
> 15M     rhel-6-server-optional-rpms/bf8ce73943e4c78fc4205924fbfaf20ec4bcb72757f03366ec1245ffe2e0803e-primary.sqlite
> 15M     rhel-6-server-optional-rpms/e4f6cad281229297c712f8dd828c2062f8fbc02c6be215ea0df35059e98b4a5d-primary.sqlite
> 124M    rhel-6-server-rpms/5a411e3bf6a743656636e6baaec1680eec3480cf69acb79aad11c535862f2787-primary.sqlite
> 124M    rhel-6-server-rpms/60daa8229ca2386d6c7f319ce1fd819a46109e0b7a42c90e48acde23c3b200f6-primary.sqlite
> 124M    rhel-6-server-rpms/8592d0cd0b2e358c7850dee130497cb8969a72b9ac28cddc13a054caccee6d65-primary.sqlite
> 124M    rhel-6-server-rpms/f5798fe075da31815c5e43356a10c208af55a972b61fea37d63ea6edb3a78cae-primary.sqlite
> ```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you run `yum` under not privileged user it uses as a cache directory the directory `/var/tmp` or what is set by the shell variable `TMPDIR`. So you can change the default behavior by running `yum` like this:

```
TMPDIR=/tmp yum check-update
TMPDIR=/tmp yum makecache
```

The same way you can run `yum` to clean up the cache directory:

```
TMPDIR=/tmp yum clean metadata
TMPDIR=/tmp yum clean all
```

When you use `clean all` option, ignore the warnings about rpmdb files as the user doesn't have priviledges to do so.

Finally, you can export the `TMPDIR` variable to not use it repeatedly when running `yum`:

```
export TMPDIR=/tmp
yum check-update
yum clean metadata
```

Comment: Can't believe yum would do that without warning you first...another option is to just nuke those directories...